# Rvest - Combine different paragraphs that belong to one speech

Tags: r, parsing, rvest

I am trying to scrape XML data with the rvest package in Rstudio. In some cases, I have several paragraphs in one speech, but when I try to scrape them, I get one entry for each paragraph. I want to combine them as I will later match them with other information stored in the XML file like speaker, speaker id and others, so I need the correct number of entries for each later column of my dataframe.

My xml data structure looks like this:

```
"<SPEECH>
<SPEAKER NAME="X" SPEAKERID="Y">
</SPEAKER>
<PARA>
TEXT XY....
</PARA>
<PARA>
TEXT Z...
</PARA>
</SPEECH>
```

I used this code.

```
url = "url" #url of xml document
page <- read_html(url) #read as html

speech <- page %>%
  html_elements("para") %>% #access xml element "para" for paragraph
  html_text() ##extract text
```

I get now a character vector with 120 entries, but I only have 65 interventions (speeches) and unfortunately, every paragraph (XY), (Z), ... (i) equals one entry in my character vector. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could collapse all paragraphs into a single string:

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
xml_str <- '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SPEECH>
<SPEAKER NAME="X" SPEAKERID="Y">
</SPEAKER>
<PARA>
TEXT XY....
</PARA>
<PARA>
TEXT Z...
</PARA>
</SPEECH>'

read_html(xml_str) %>% 
  html_elements("para") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  paste(collapse = "\n---\n")
#> [1] "\nTEXT XY....\n\n---\n\nTEXT Z...\n"
```

Or perhaps collect all details from XML to a named list so it can be converted to a dataframe:

```r
read_html(xml_str) %>% 
  {
    list(name = html_element(., "speaker") %>% html_attr("name"),
         speaker_id = html_element(., "speaker") %>% html_attr("speakerid"),
         para = html_elements(., "para") %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
    )
  } %>% 
  bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   name  speaker_id para       
#>   <chr> <chr>      <chr>      
#> 1 X     Y          TEXT XY....
#> 2 X     Y          TEXT Z...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>